# hadoop1.0.3 & nutch1.5.1 can't update crawlDB

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I try to deploy hadoop on my server then I build nutch1.5.1 using [this tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchHadoopTutorial) to run nutch on hadoop. I hadn't got any error message in log files but the crawlDB can't update any urls so that crawlDB always has the init urls.

In my development ENV I run the org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 that it's working fine.

In my server side I run the script something like that:

```
./runtime/deploy/bin/nutch crawl urls -dir crawl -depth 3 -topN 5
```

the urls file I had copied in HDFS.

Do I need to config something?